# How I get checkbox value when it is uncheck in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

Here it's my html code

```
<tr class="action_table_row">
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="235"></td>
        <td>Location</td>
          <td>
            <select class="delBoyChange">
            <option value="4" selected>ABC</option>
        </select>
    </td>
<td><button class="btn btn-default btn-xs delete_mapping"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button></td>
```

How I get uncheck check box value. I tried...

```
$( ".delBoyChange" ).change(function() {
    var locationIds = [];
    if($("input:checkbox").prop('checked')){
    $("input:checkbox:checked").each(function() {
    if(this.value != "on"){
        locationIds.push(parseInt(this.value));
    }
    });
    }else{
    alert($("input:checkbox").prop('checked', false).value);
    var locId = $("input:checkbox").prop('checked', false).value;
    console.log("locId-> " + locId)
    locationIds.push(parseInt(locId));
    }
});
```

to get an unchecked checkbox's value, but I got: 
**undefine**

here its my line give me wrong value

```
var locId = $("input:checkbox").prop('checked', false).value;
```

Comment: As a side note, when using parseInt, you should add the radix parameter. Look at this link for more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: if you could improve the indents of your code, that would increase readability.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.value` is a DOM element attribute, jQuery objects have a `.val()` method:

```
$("input:checkbox").prop('checked', false).val();
```

Comment: *"on"*? Well you are selecting every checkbox on the page... and `.val()` return the value of the first one. Your first checkbox in the page must have the value *"on"*.

Answer (score 0):

Your jquery is wrong. It should be like this.

```
if (!$("input:checkbox").attr("checked"))
    var locId = $("input:checkbox").val();
```